# Neo4j Cypher extracting data from collection using 'and/or' logical operators

Tags: collections, neo4j, cypher, extract, logical-operators

I have a collection and I need to extract a name and id from each node and return them together to avoid post processing. I am trying:

```
extract(c IN nodes(c)| c.name +\': \'+ c.id) as results
```

The problem is that when a node without a name value is encountered it doesn't return anything.

Is there a way like 'and/or' to make the c.name optional allowing it to still return the c.id and a NULL for c.name?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought at first that you could use `toString` to turn nulls into an empty string, but that doesn't seem to work.  `coalesce` should help, though:

```
extract(c IN nodes(c)| coalesce(c.name, '') +\': \'+ c.id) as results
```

Comment: You can also turn them i into a collection with: `extract(c IN nodes(c)|  [c.name , c.id])` or map  `extract(c IN nodes(c)|  {name: c.name , id: c.id})`

Comment: Thanks to both of you. All three work perfectly. Returning as a collection or map gives me both values broken out into an array and averages about 270kb per query where as coalesce returns the two values combined as a string averaging 70kb per query.